# docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, macos-ventura

Facing this error

```
    def _retrieve_server_version(self):
        try:
            return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
        except KeyError:
            raise DockerException(
                'Invalid response from docker daemon: key "ApiVersion"'
                ' is missing.'
            )
        except Exception as e:
INFO    2022-11-17 19:24:43,005 Done running pytest tests [tests_runner.py:run_pytest:79]
ERROR   2022-11-17 19:24:43,013 pytest exited with a nonzero exit code: 1 [tests_runner.py:run_pytest:83]
INFO    2022-11-17 19:24:43,020 Removing the test sidecar [live_cp_test.py:remove_sidecar:68]
WARNING 2022-11-17 19:24:45,752 Skipping 'prepare_artifacts', requires cloudbuild [live_cp_test.py:prepare_artifacts:74]
WARNING 2022-11-17 19:24:45,756 Skipping 'prepare_and_send_slack_update' (Requires cloudbuild) [live_cp_test.py:prepare_and_send_slack_update:97]
>           raise DockerException(
                f'Error while fetching server API version: {e}'
            )
E           docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

while I use pytest plugin called `pytest-docker-compose:3.2.1` to run my services with docker-compose.

OS:MacOS monterey 12.6

docker version

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        baeda1f
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:01:18 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           desktop-linux
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.14.1 (91661)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       3056208
  Built:            Tue Oct 25 18:00:19 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.9
  GitCommit:        1c90a442489720eec95342e1789ee8a5e1b9536f
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

docker-compose version.

```
Docker Compose version v2.12.2
```

This issue does not occur when docker is fresh installed, but once the system goes for a reboot I see this every time I use the pytest plugin.

command used to run the program.

```
docker run --env-file ./env.list -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /Users/f/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud -v /Users/f/.docker:/root/.docker -v /Users/f/work/tests:/Users/f/work/tests --net=host -ti --rm test_image /Users/f/work/tests/run_in_docker bash -c '2>&1 make install && poetry run e2e live-cp-test --tests-path tests
```